# Manage Facebook Session in Activity

Tags: android, facebook

So I have the facebook login fragment setup, but because I am building a mutli-tab+swipe app with SectionsPagerAdapter, I built the login (splash screen) into a new activity. How do I manage the session now that its in a activity?

EDIT

What I have moved to doing is putting the session items in SessionActivity and extending by all activities that use it. I then setup a login activity and made that my main entry point.

```
public class SessionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String TAG = "SessionActivity";
protected UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

    }
};

protected void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logged in...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        //finish();
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logged out...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);  
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

My login as the main entry point for the app. This way the session is kickstarted once the user logs in.

```
public class FacebookActivity extends SessionActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
```

}

At this point the onSessionStateChange should handle showing the login screen or the the working activity, however I'm getting stuck in a infinity loop opening and closing the login in this example.

```
    protected void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logged in...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
        //finish();
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logged out...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whre are you actually opening the session? Are you using the supplied LoginButton somewhere? Since you're using the activeSession, you can just call Session.getActiveSession in another activity. The activeSession is a static, so it's available across all activities once created.

Comment: I updated my post. Since the last post/edit, I have setup a SessionActivity that is extended by all other activities. I then setup  the FacebookActivity as they main entry point. So once the user logs in I should be able to close the login form and send them to the main app. At that point the session is running, so I would need to do is look for a logged out status within the SessionActivity callback. Only problem I'm running into is that I'm getting hit with a infinity loop. I'm about to add my own int check to insure it does not keep popping the intent. Unless there is a better way?

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and try https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: Nice, very nice. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

In the end I setup my fb session using control SessionActivity as a base, and extending it with whatever activity I was using. I then setup a FacebookActivity for the login process. When a activity that has extended the SessionActivity find it does not have a fb session it will open the FacebookActivity. If they back out of the FacebookActivity it will open itself again which makes for a nice splash screen all around.

```
public class SessionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

protected GraphUser userDetails;

private static final String TAG = "SessionActivity";
protected UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;   

public Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

    }
};

protected void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
            getFbUserDetails(session);
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FacebookActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void getFbUserDetails(final Session session) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Making fb API call...");
    // Make an API call to get user data and define a 
    // new callback to handle the response.
    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, 
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            // If the response is successful
            Log.i(TAG, "Processing fb response...");
            if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                if (user !=null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Setting userDetails...");
                    userDetails = user;
                }
            }
            if (response.getError() != null) {
                // Handle errors, will do so later.
                Log.i(TAG, "Error while processing fb response...");
            }
        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();
}   
@Override
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(session==null){                      
        // try to restore from cache
        session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(this);
    }

    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);  
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(session==null){                      
        // try to restore from cache
        session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(this);
    }

    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);  
    }           
}
```

}

```
public class FacebookActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String TAG = "SessionActivity";
protected UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}

public Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

protected void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logged in...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //finish();
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logged out...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);  
    }       

    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

```
public class MyActivity extends SessionActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/authButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```